# Is that Possible for NTLM Authentication in Mobile for Sharepoint Site?

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2010, mobile-safari, ntlm

Now a Days I want to use Login Control For Sharepoint Mobile page. But I cant got any referrence site for this. I have been use one link in my custom mobile page and navigation url for this url go to window authentication page.. Is that possible?. pls reply me asap.

Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the web application to use form based authentication. Then you can use the build in login form. see here for details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806890.aspx

Or you can use a UAG server and publish the SharePoint web application.